# Some doubts about how work this DCG grammar for subset of natural language in Prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am studying DCG grammar for natural language processing using Prolog and I have some doubts about if I have understand it correctly or if I am missing something.

This is my DCG grammar:

```
sentence2(VP) --> noun_phrase2(Actor),
              verb_phrase2(Actor, VP).

/* A noun phrase is a proper name of a person (that is unified in the Name variable) */
noun_phrase2(Name) --> properName(Name).

/* A verb_phrase can be an intransitive verb */
verb_phrase2(Actor, VP) --> intrans_verb(Actor, VP).

/* A verb_phrase can be a transitive verb followed by an object complement
verb_phrase2(Somebody, VP) --> trans_verb(Somebody, Something, VP),
                               noun_phrase2(Something).

/* The meaning of a proper name john is john
   The meaning of a proper name mary is mary */
properName(john) --> [john].
properName(mary) --> [mary].

intrans_verb(Actor, paints(Actor)) --> [paints].

trans_verb(Somebody, Something, likes(Somebody, Something)) --> [likes].
```

So this grammar can accept phrase like: **[john, paints]** that have the meaning: **paints(john)**

I would see if my idea about how I reach this meaning is correct.

So I think that this is what happen when I execute the following query:

```
?- sentence2(Meaning, [john, paints], []).
Meaning = paints(john)
```

**[john paints]** it is my **final sentence** that I have to evaluate and say if it belong to my language or not.

A sentence have to be formed in the following way:

```
sentence2(VP) --> noun_phrase2(Actor),
                  verb_phrase2(Actor, VP).
```

(by something that is **noun phrase** followed by something that is a **verb phrase**.

A **noun phrase** is composed in this way:

```
noun_phrase2(Name) --> properName(Name).
```

so a **noun phrase** is a **proper name**

The meaning of a **proper name** is simple because by this line:

```
properName(john) --> [john].
```

I am simply say that the **john is a proper name** and I am adding a parameter to the DCG grammar that specify its meaning. So: **the semantic meaning of the proper name john is john**

So, as the **meaning** of a **noun phrase** is the **same meaning** of the **proper name** (because the variables **Name** unify)

So in the previous case the **meaning** ot the **noun_phrase2** predicate is **john** and the first evalutation step of my original sentence is end.

Now I have to evaluate that the second part is a **verbal phrase** by the predicate: **verb_phrase2(Actor, VP)**

A **verbal phrase** could be, as in this case, an **intransitive verb**:

```
verb_phrase2(Actor, VP) --> intrans_verb(Actor, VP).
```

An intransitive verb is definied in this way:

```
intrans_verb(Actor, paints(Actor)) --> [paints].
```

So the word **paints** is an intransitive verb and it's meaning is **paints(Actor)** where **Actor** is a variable that dependnds from the context (in this case **Actor** rappresent **who do the action, who paints**)

So, it do backtrack to **verb_phrase2(Actor, VP)** to verify **verb_phrase2(Actor, VP)**

Now Actor still remain a not yet unified variable and its meaning is **VP = paints(Actor)**

So, it is verified that **paints** is an intransitive verb and its meaning is **paints(Actor)**

So execute backtrack to the original **sentence2(VP)** predicate where I have just verified the **noun_phrase2(Actor)** predicate and in which **Actor = john**

So I have something like this situation:

```
sentence2(VP) --> noun_phrase2(john),
                  verb_phrase2(john, paints(john)).
```

So the final **VP is unified to paints(john)**

Is it my reasoning correct or am I missing something? Is it a good way to reasoning in Prolog way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please ask a specific, short question. Include relevant code without excessive comments.

Here's how.

---

Given the DCG rules

```prolog
sentence2(VP) --> noun_phrase2(Actor),verb_phrase2(Actor, VP).
noun_phrase2(Name) --> properName(Name).
verb_phrase2(Actor, VP) --> intrans_verb(Actor, VP).
verb_phrase2(Somebody, VP) --> trans_verb(Somebody, Something, VP),
                                 noun_phrase2(Something).
properName(john) --> [john].
properName(mary) --> [mary].
intrans_verb(Actor, paints(Actor)) --> [paints].
trans_verb(Somebody, Something, likes(Somebody, Something)) --> [likes].
```

how does the following achieve its result?

```
?- sentence2(Meaning, [john, paints], []).
Meaning = paints(john)
```

---

Answer:

The above rules are equivalent to

```prolog
sentence2(VP, L, Z):- noun_phrase2(Actor, L, L2), 
                      verb_phrase2(Actor, VP, L2, Z).
noun_phrase2(Name, L, Z):- properName(Name, L, Z).    
verb_phrase2(Actor, VP, L, Z):- intrans_verb(Actor, VP, L, Z). 
verb_phrase2(Somebody, VP, L, Z):- trans_verb(Somebody, Something, VP, L, L2),
                                   noun_phrase2(Something, L2, Z).    
properName(john, L, Z):- 
    L = [john | Z].         %// 'john' is present in the input stream
properName(mary, L, Z):- 
    L = [mary | Z].         %// 'mary' is present in the input stream
/* an alternative definition 
properName(X) --> [X], { member(X, [john, mary]) }.
   %% would be translated as
properName(X, L, Z):- L = [X | Z], member(X, [john, mary]). 
*/    
intrans_verb(Actor, paints(Actor), L, Z):- 
    L = [paints | Z].       %// 'paints' is present in the input stream    
trans_verb(Somebody, Something, likes(Somebody, Something), L, Z):-
    L = [likes | Z].        %// 'likes' is present in the input stream
```

In particular,

```prolog
?- sentence2(Meaning, [john, paints], []).    

?- noun_phrase2(Actor, [john, paints], L2),                    
   verb_phrase2(Actor, Meaning, L2, []).

  ?- noun_phrase2(Actor, [john, paints], L2).
  ?- properName(Actor, [john, paints], L2).   
  ?- properName(john, [john, paints], L2).            { Actor=john }
  !- [john, paints] = [john | [paints]]               { L2=[paints] }

  ?- verb_phrase2(john, Meaning, [paints], []).
  ?- intrans_verb(john, Meaning, [paints], []).
  ?- intrans_verb(john, paints(john), [paints], []).  { Meaning=paints(john) }
  !- [paints] = [paints | []]

!-
```

Comment: Ok, now it is pretty clear how the DCG grammar will translate in Prolog rule, I have use the trace to understand its logic...but my answer was more related to: "Take a first DCG grammar that rappresent only the syntax of a language, how can I modify it (adding parameters) to handle also the semantic meaning of this language?"

All my discussion will more related to how do it without passing for the Prolog rule...however now everything is much clear :-)

Comment: @AndreaNobili next time, please try to ask more specific, focused, *one* question. *Small*. :)